# What are the FEDRAMP "complementary controls"?

Tags: compliance, governance, fedramp

Quoting the [FedRAMP official FAQ](https://www.fedramp.gov/faqs/):

> FedRAMP requirements include additional controls above the standard NIST baseline controls in NIST SP 800-53 Revision 4. These additional controls address the unique elements of cloud computing to ensure all federal data is secure in cloud environments.

However when I download the list of controls via the Official Fedramp Website ([see this for "HIGH"](https://www.fedramp.gov/assets/resources/documents/FedRAMP_High_Security_Controls.xlsx), and similar links for the other levels), I get what looks like the NIST 800-53 controls. Depending on the FedRAMP impact level, a subset of the NIST controls are selected.

So, what are those "additional controls above the NIST baseline"? I can’t find those on the web.

Comment: Are you sure that fedramp needs its own tag?

Comment: How about I'm unsure that it doesn't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What FedRAMP calls "complementary controls" are simply the classic NIST "security control enhancements" selected for FedRAMP, and that are available in the usual NIST templates.

It was just a vocabulary issue..